# GDS, OASIS, etc. vs LEF/DEF: which is better?

Tags: layout

I have two questions here. By the way, I have searched about the differences but I wanna know more. So,

1. Can LEF/DEF format describe everything that GDS, OASIS, etc. formats, can? What can I do with LEF without the DEF, and DEF without LEF? Why would I use one of them instead of both?
2. I've heard that now LEF/DEF is becoming popular over the above mentioned formats. So what's the main reason for this? I mean, LEF/DEF is in plain, ASCII format, and GDS is binary. Isn't having binary "safer"?

Comment: What do these acronyms mean? You can't assume that everyone on the site will know what you're talking about. (though it's very possible that it's some standard for a field I'm just unfamiliar with)

Comment: If someone reads "GDS" and doesn't know what it means, then they wouldn't know what Graphic Database System means, either.